# mongoose findOne() function not returning item specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get a single item using mongoose in javascript and cannot get it to work. The item is titled "name" in my database and when I use .get with /products it works fine. All of my methods that get ALL items work great, I am just having trouble with the single items. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extend: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ShoppingCartDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const productSchema = {
  name: String,
  price: String,
  quantity: Int
};

const Products = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);
//sets route to all items in products database
app.route("/products")
//gets ALL items in cart
.get(function (req, res) {
  Products.find(function(err, foundProducts) {
    console.log(foundProducts);
    if (!err) {
      res.send(foundProducts);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
})
//deletes ALL items in cart
.delete(function(req, res) {
  Products.deleteMany(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("All products removed from shopping cart");
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  })
});
//changes route to single item based on name
app.route("/products/:itemName")

.get(function(req, res) {
  Products.findOne({name: req.params.itemName}, function(err, foundItem){
    if (foundItem) {
      res.send(foundItem);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
})

.delete(function(req, res) {
  Products.deleteOne(
    {name: req.params.itemName},function(err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Success");
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});




app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

My database:

```
{
        "_id": "5e1ca39ef94f6e20827ee890",
        "name": "orange",
        "price": "0.99",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1ca39ef94f6e20827ee893",
        "name": "apple",
        "price": "1.5",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1ca39ef94f6e20827ee896",
        "name": "bread",
        "price": "3.99",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1ca39ef94f6e20827ee899",
        "name": "milk",
        "price": "4.99",
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1ca39ef94f6e20827ee89c",
        "name": "coffee",
        "price": "4.99",
        "quantity": 2
    }
```

Comment: `.findOne()` will return a document if nay match found or else it will return `null` in your code here :: `.get(function(req, res) {
  Products.findOne({name: req.params.itemName}, function(err, foundItem){
    if (foundItem) {
      res.send(foundItem);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
})` In the else it should be `err` if can be a string `'Item with `{name}` not found'` & before `if()` check you need to check for `if(err)` & return error from there..Anyhow what do you mean by not returning specified item ?? what is response ? did you log `itemName` & `foundItem` ??

Comment: ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot GET /products/orange</pre>
</body>

</html>``` This is the error I get when I try to return "orange"

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

Quantity should be `Number`, not `Int`:

```
const productSchema = {
    name: String,
    price: String,
    quantity: Number
};
```

`extended: true` not `extend: true` on your `bodyParser`:

```
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
    })
);
```

This way I am getting a `200` on the show route.